# UX StackExchange Bottom Notice poor link color contrast

Tags: feature-request, bug, design

It bugs me that the "bottom-notice" links on the UX pages have such poor contrast.  The color contrast of #E8BF6C against a #FFFFFF background is 1.74:1.

[WCAG 2.0's luminosity contrast](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/WD-WCAG20-20060427/complete.html#luminosity-contrastdef) algorithm recommends at least 4.5:1

[image]

Can that be changed?  If this isn't the correct place to suggest this, feel free to close it.

**Suggestion:** For example it could be changed to #CC3300 which would provide proper contrast with the white background, ok contrast with the non-link text, and still differentiate it from the standard blue links (which I'm guessing was the intention of making it a non-standard link text color to begin with?